# Pre is failing with ComponentValues cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: bazel

After sync my pre is failing with below error

```
ERROR in /Users/<user_name>/.cache/bazel/ee4f3b1626bb7a13489180af6bead5fb/execroot/core/ui-sfdc-api/java/src/ui/aura/components/Components.java (at line 1712)
    private final ComponentValues impl;
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ComponentValues cannot be resolved to a type
```

I tried couple of solutions. like

Solution 1. cleaning cache

Solution 2. Installing Xcode and ran  bazel clean --expunge

Solution 3. corecli :configure-ports -nphx-nexus-proxy.internal.salesforce.com

but none of them worked.

Comment: What do you mean with sync? `bazel sync`? What is pre?

Comment: Are you sure downloaded the right dependencies in the workspace file ? Its hard to understand without the code base.